# How to embed external file contents in org file?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-link

I'm creating a simple bash tool that uses various flags/arguments from the user, and I'm using an `org` file for the documentation. I have several examples and I'd like to include some explanation of each. Instead of copying the code from each example into the file, I'd like to create a link to the file and display the contents in the org file. Something like

```
This example does such and such...
[[/path/to/ex-file-1.sh]]

my-tool -f "user-input" # these are the contents of ex-file-1.sh

While this example does this and that...
[[/path/to/ex-file-2/sh]] 

my-tool -r "user-input # these are the contents of ex-file-2.sh
```

This way, I don't have to modify the `README.org` if I modify the individual example files. I'd also like to do the same thing with the contents of the tool's help (which is activated with the `-h` flag). Basically I want modifying the documentation to be less tedious.

I know that images can be embedded into `org` files (and are even visible within the file before exporting), so I would assume the same is possible with text? What do I need to use for this? Or I am I just being too lazy with my documentation?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [the `include` keyword](http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html#Include-files).

Comment: ... and maybe export README.org to a (different) org file: that should pick up the inclusions explicitly.

Comment: @Nick @Juancho Yep. Good call guys. I'm now calling this file `README` so when using `org-org-export-to-org` it automatically creates `README.org`. When I type `C-c C-e` I don't see an option to export to `org`, so I just put a comment at the bottom of the document with `(org-org-export-to-org)` and run this when I want to generate the `org-file`.

Comment: I thought org is always available as an export option, but I guess you need to customize `org-export-backends` to get it in the menu.

Comment: I'm using Spacemacs, so who knows.. Also, feel free to type up an answer, and I'll mark it as correct (I can edit your answer as needed to provide more details.. for noobs.. like me)

Comment: You can use the [org-transclusion](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion) package for this, see [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45426/how-to-expand-external-files-inline-on-orgmode/75432#75432) answer.