# Displaying contents of another file in an Org-mode buffer

Tags: org-mode

I have a file whose contents I would like to view dynamically from a generic Org-mode buffer.

For example, suppose I have a file called `data.csv`, and I'd like to display some of its contents when I visit `study.org`. To make up one way that this might look, `study.org` might appear as follows:

```
# -*- mode: Org; coding: utf-8; -*-
...
#+INCLUDE: "data.csv" :head 5
#+BEGIN_INCLUDE
id,name,count
1,recursion,48
2,exercise,55
3,ambrosia,85
4,division,16
#+END_INCLUDE
...
```

I see that someone has asked this question in the context of the Org-mode export
 mechanism ([How to embed external file contents in org file?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31772/how-to-embed-external-file-contents-in-org-file)), but I don't see a way to include external file content in an Org buffer.

Does Org-mode support this sort of thing?

Comment: You can use the [org-transclusion](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion) package for this, see [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45426/how-to-expand-external-files-inline-on-orgmode/75432#75432) answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a shell source code block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output drawer
head -n 5 data.csv
#+END_SRC
```

Then you hit `C-c C-c` inside the block and run the source code which will show below the first five lines of the file in a results block

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more integrated and less hacky, but this does the job!

Comment: Here is a collection of links that provide a more integrated experience:
https://github.com/alphapapa/transclusion-in-emacs